# What is the recommended way of load balancing a multi-master/multi-slave Jenkins setup

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I would like to setup an N-master x M-slave Jenkins build/execution farm.

I'd like to allow multiple projects to run their own Jenkins master server, each distributing their builds into the same pool of Jenkins slaves.

So each slave will have separately configured workspaces and so on.

What is the recommended way of load balancing the jobs across the slaves?
i.e. if Master 1 has kicked off a job on Slave 1, and Master 2 comes along to run a job, I'd like it to pick a slave other than 1 to run that job on.

What is the recommended way of setting that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways you could do this. You could create the job to run on any open executor. An executor is what Jenkins runs jobs on. Assuming each instance of Jenkins has one executor, if one master executes something on Slave1 it will then take up one executor. So when master two tries to run something, it will run it on Slave2 (or any other executor that is available), since Slave1 is busy.

This depends on two things:

1. that all jobs can run on any available machine/executor
2. that each Jenkins has one executor.

Jenkins does manage load as best as it can, but I would recommend having one executor for every core available on the machine, so your machines aren't flogged down, and let Jenkins handle where they are actually run. You can even tie jobs to specific machines as well.

Good luck.

Comment: Sounds sensible ... we are setting up an initial pool of 4 or 5 slave machines which will be sufficient to test this approach and I will report back when it's been checked out. Thanks!

Comment: You can also enforce this by limiting where projects can be run. ie Salve A & B are Unix machines (labeled with a 'Unix' name) and C & D are windows machines (labeled with a 'Windows' name). In your project, you can enforce that it only builds on 'Unix' slaves, which would limit it to A & B.

Comment: @puug this is true, but i believe he wants jobs to be more flexible.

Comment: correct. I don't want the projects to have to care where their jobs are executed, we will just have a permanent pool of essentially identical slaves, but rather than have one master and have everyone submit jobs on that, it will be easier for several reasons to allow individual projects to have their own master jenkins server, and just (one off) set that up to point to all of the slave machines. Some brief networking troubles preventing us testing this setup ... still working through those first ...

Comment: You explained what could be done, but gave no specifics on how to actually do it...

Comment: @Garen https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines